# Trouble rendering shadowmap for planets

Tags: opengl, java, libgdx, shaders, fragment-shader

Im currently trying to create a game where you visit planets in LibGDX for Java. To do this I use a TiledMap which is basically just an array of tiles to represent the planets themselves. To get the necessary curvature, I use a Shader; it works by assigning an angle to every vertex and placing it according to the camera position. It looks like this: [image: this]

I now use a shadowmap to get lighting into the game. This is done by drawing shades of grey onto a texture and strechting the texture over the gameplay after that (specifically a FrameBuffer). Without any shaders it looks like this: [image: this].

My problem now is to turn the shadowmap into a planetlike shape (circular shape). You now have to use a fragment shader, but I dont really know the method. If you have an idea that might solve this problem, just post it. I've been working on this for a few weeks now and haven't made much progress.

If you want to know what idea I had take a look at this:

This is the fragment shader I tried to use to render the shadowmap, it resulted in [image: this]. As you can see its got a basic circular form, but is kinda distorted (I know the problem arises out of how the angles are used, but Im not sure how to fix it yet). This is how the texture is represented in the shader (with uv): https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOT0f.png

```
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

uniform float TEXTURE_WIDTH;
uniform float TEXTURE_HEIGHT;
uniform float VIEWPORT_WIDTH;
uniform float VIEWPORT_HEIGHT;
uniform float CAM_X;
uniform float CAM_Y;

varying vec2 uv;
varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {

    // THE RATIO OF TEXTURE WIDTH TO TEXTURE_HEIGHT WHICH YOU MULTIPLY WITH UV.X TO NOT ALLOW STRETCHING
    // (LOOK AT HOW THE TEXTURE IS REPRESENTED TO UNDERSTAND)
    float k = TEXTURE_WIDTH / TEXTURE_HEIGHT;
    uv.x *= k;

    // THE CENTER OF THE PLANET RELATIVE TO TEXTURE_HEIGHT AS 1
    vec2 m;
    m.x = (k * VIEWPORT_WIDTH) / (2.0 * TEXTURE_WIDTH);
    m.y = - ((CAM_Y - 0.5 * VIEWPORT_HEIGHT) / TEXTURE_HEIGHT);

    // THE DISTANCE FROM CURRENT UV COORDINATE TO CENTER
    float d = distance(uv, m);

    // THE RANGE OF ANGLES
    float a = abs(atan(m.x/m.y)) * 2.0;

    // THE ANGLE OF THE CURRENT UV COORDINATE
    // + THE LEFTOFER ANGLE FROM HOW MUCH THE PLAYER HAS MOVED FROM THE CLOSEST INTEGER POSITION
    float angle = atan((uv.x - m.x)/(uv.y - m.y)) + (CAM_X - floor(CAM_X)) * (a / VIEWPORT_WIDTH);

    // ASIGN THE DISTANCE AND ANGLE TO ONE POINT IN THE TEXTURE
    uv.x = ((angle + 0.5 * a) / a)*(VIEWPORT_WIDTH / TEXTURE_WIDTH);
    uv.y = d + m.y;

    // GET THE COLOR OF THE TEXTURE AT THIS POINT
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, uv) * v_color;
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```